# c++ array workabout solution for char

Tags: c++, char

I wish for it to cout 'A+' however it only cout '+'

with reference to -
" char grade [MAX] = {'A+'...} "

```
const int MAX = 11;

int main ()
{
    char grade [MAX] = {'A+', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'F'};
    float point [MAX] = {5.0, 5.0, 4.5, 4.0, 3.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.0};

    welcome ();

    cout << grade [0];
    cout << point [0];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because `A+` is a string of  two `chars` (`A` and `+`), and not a single `char`. You need store these values in an array of `std::string`.

```
std::string grade [MAX] = {"A+", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "F"};
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because 'A+' isn't a character literal, 'A+' is 2 characters, 'A' and '+'. And thus, `grade[0]` only holds 'A', the '+' is lost. Make it a string literal instead and save it in a `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
std::string grade [MAX] = {"A+", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "F"};
```

Comment: @Jarvis Oh, yeah.

Comment: Out of curiousity, are you really Bill Gates ? @GillBates

Comment: _"And thus, grade[0] only holds 'A', the '+' is lost."_ Actually, as a multicharacter literal, the result is implementation-dependent. If you read the question properly, you'll see that here it "holds" or prints `+`, not `A`.

Comment: @Jarvis: Yes, he is really Bill Gates.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The part about '+' didn't even catch my eye. I'm getting too old for this I think. I should start investing.

Comment: Really ? Or is it sarcasm ? You have any proof ? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Can you confirm ? @GillBates

Comment: @Jarvis: *Facepalm*.

Comment: @Jarvis: Are you really Jarvis?

Comment: Yeah, but me and Mr. Stark answer collectively sometimes from the same account. @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [This](http://puu.sh/u2Pkg/bb4b2eb6d6.jpg) was actually me a couple of days ago.

Comment: @GillBates: Heh, nice job

Answer (score 0):

Use string

```
#include <string>
```

as char support max of 1 input unlike string.